# The robot doesn't move when I use turtle_teleop_key

Tags: ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to connect ROS with Gazebo, to do it I'm following this tutorial: [Robotic simulation scenarios with Gazebo and ROS](https://www.generationrobots.com/blog/en/2015/02/robotic-simulation-scenarios-with-gazebo-and-ros/).

And running ROS Lunar version 1.13.6 on an Ubuntu Xenial 16.04.4 LTS.

I did everything in the tutorial until the section **Adding a camera**. But when I do:

```
rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key /turtle1/cmd_vel:=/mybot/cmd_vel
```

The robot doesn't move. It only moves a little when a press down arrow key.

Maybe the problem is here, inside the mybot.gazebo file:

```
<gazebo>
  <plugin name="differential_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
    <legacyMode>true</legacyMode>
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>100</updateRate>
    <leftJoint>left_wheel_hinge</leftJoint>
    <rightJoint>right_wheel_hinge</rightJoint>
    <wheelSeparation>${chassisWidth+wheelWidth}</wheelSeparation>
    <wheelDiameter>${2*wheelRadius}</wheelDiameter>
    <torque>20</torque>
    <commandTopic>mybot/cmd_vel</commandTopic>
    <odometryTopic>mybot/odom_diffdrive</odometryTopic>
    <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
    <robotBaseFrame>footprint</robotBaseFrame>
  </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

But I'm newbie and I don't know if there is something wrong here.

I have also tried:

```
rostopic pub -1 /mybot/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -- '[2.0, 0.0, 0.0]' '[0.0, 0.0, 1.8]'
```

But the robot doesn't move.

Do you know why the robot doesn't move? Well, it moves. When I press the down arrow key, the robot base move to the ground.

All the source code is in [Github](https://github.com/VansFannel/MyBot).

**UPDATE**

I get this warnings when I launch Gazebo:

```
DiffDrive(ns = //): missing <rosDebugLevel> default is na
DiffDrive(ns = //): missing <publishWheelTF> default is false
DiffDrive(ns = //): missing <publishWheelJointState> default is false
DiffDrive(ns = //): missing <wheelAcceleration> default is 0
DiffDrive(ns = //): missing <wheelTorque> default is 5
DiffDrive(ns = //): missing <odometrySource> default is 1
GazeboRosDiffDrive Plugin (ns = ) missing <publishTf>, defaults to 1
```

This is the rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph output:

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302493/the-robot-doesn%27t-move-when-i-use-turtle_teleop_key/) by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-09-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2018-09-05**:
Try publishing more than once, ie remove --1 and add -r 10 (rate at 10 hz)

These things don't latch unless you tell them to, do just hitting it once probably won't result in motion. It's been a while since I did the turtle demo, but I think you have to hold key or press a few times to get moving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was the Gazebo version. All ROS packages were up to date but Gazebo version was 7.0.0.

I added the Gazebo repository following this [instructions](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=install&tut=install_ubuntu&ver=7.0) and then, I updated it to version 7.14.

And now it moves!!!

---

Originally posted by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) with karma: 71 on 2018-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2018-09-07**:
You should mark an answer as correct then so it removes from the queue of unanswered questions :)